# Incorrect cell data display when scrolling UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I am facing some weird problems. Whenever I scroll my table view, my data gets replaced with other cells. Each time, it gets replaced with different cell data. I am not seeing any particular pattern in this replacement.

Comment: You're not reusing/creating you cells properly. Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and we'll be able to point mistakes

Comment: Need to see code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's code for how to properly reuse a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {        
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text =  [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

If you provide your code we could modify that instead of giving you generic examples.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.But if I finish bracket for if(cell == nil) after cell allocation line,my date gets overlapped with each other.

Comment: @user If your dates are overlapping each other that's because you're not handling the dates correctly. This is the right way to handle reusable cells. If you're serious about getting help you should post some code. My guess is that you're either adding a new subview each time or if you're drawing them manually you're not clearing the surface before you draw the date.

Comment: This is not only an issue of cell reuse. In iOS 6.0, there's a great way to tackle this issue: http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/

Answer (score 8):

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks Rams.I got the solution.I didnt give reuseIdentifier and it worked perfect for me.

Comment: thank you really it's working very well. My cell is changing everytime .

Comment: This is very very important note. I used to use identifier everytime so i did not even think about not to use it for reusing.

Answer (score 4):

If you've created a custom cell, you may have to implement `prepareForReuse` on your `UITableViewCell` subclass to clear out cell data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on iOS 7 and storyboard while I never had this problem with the same code on elder Xcode-SDK versions, and trying lots of suggestions from stackoverflow, I couldn't fix it, and guess what?! Apple's [TableView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) has the well-explained guide.
There's even no need to use `cell==nil`.

So to create a custom tableview cell using storyboard that would be reused properly, you can take two different approacesh. I personally prefer the first one which is more straightforward, but I put both solutions here.

***First Approach***

1. Create a project using the Master-Detail Application template and select the Use Storyboards option.
2. On the storyboard canvas, select the master view controller.
3. In the Identity inspector, verify that Class is set to the custom MasterViewController class.
4. Select the table view inside the master view controller.
5. In the Attributes inspector, verify that the Content pop-up menu is set to Dynamic Prototypes.
6. Select the prototype cell.
7. In the Attributes inspector, choose Custom in the Style pop-up menu.
8. Enter a reuse identifier in the Identifier text field.
   This is the same reuse identifier you send to the table view in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` message.
9. Choose Disclosure Indicator in the Accessory pop-up menu.
10. Drag objects from the Library onto the cell.
    For this example, drag two label objects and position them near the ends of the cell (leaving room for the accessory view).
11. Select the objects and set their attributes, sizes, and autoresizing characteristics.

An important attribute to set for the programmatic portion of this procedure is each object’s `tag` property. Find this property in the `View` section of the `Attributes inspector` and assign each object a unique integer.

Now write the code you would normally write to obtain the table view’s data. (For this example, the only data you need is the row number of each cell.) Implement the data source method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to create a new cell from the prototype and populate it with data, in a manner similar to this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    UILabel *label;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

There are a few aspects of this code to note:

- The string identifier you assign to the prototype cell is the same string you pass to the table view in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.
- **Because the prototype cell is defined in a storyboard, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method always returns a valid cell. You don’t need to check the return value against nil and create a cell manually.**
- **The code gets the labels in the cell by calling `viewWithTag:`, passing in their tag integers. It can then set the textual content of the labels.**

***Second Approach***

If you prefer not to use tags, you can use an alternative method for setting the content in the cell. Define a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass with outlet properties for the objects you want to set. In the storyboard, associate the new class with the prototype cell and connect the outlets to the corresponding objects in the cell.

*To use outlets for the custom cell content*

1. Add an Objective-C class named MyTableViewCell to your project.
2. Add the following code to the interface in `MyTableViewCell.h`:

   @interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;
   @end
3. Add the following code to the implementation in `MyTableViewCell.m`:

   @synthesize firstLabel, secondLabel;
4. Add the following line of code to the source file that implements the data source:

   #import "MyTableViewCell.h"
5. Use the `Identity inspector` to set the Class of the prototype cell to `MyTableViewCell`.
6. Use the Connections inspector to connect the two outlets in the prototype cell to their corresponding labels.
   [image]
7. Implement the data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

   cell.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
   cell.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

   return cell;
   }
   ```

The code gains access to the labels in the cell using accessor methods (dot notation is used here). The code can then set the textual content of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but still...
I've encountered this problem. If others sees this problem one day.
I didn't notice, and don't remember why I did that, but I wrote the configuration of the cell INSIDE the test `if (cell == nil)` instead of writing it AFTER. I must have been tired this day...