# Improper placement of images on scrolling the tableview objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

hello guys i am downloading images for each product from my server and set it up inside a custom cell of my **UITableView** and caching them on disk after scrolling down the **UITableView** images are miss placed what i mean the new cells takes the old values of the previous cells after searching of this topic i found different solution either to use **prepareForReuse** or checking on the cell if its nil or not both of them does not fit my case.

**CODE:**
**MyCustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mirsaProduct.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIWebView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "SDWebImageCompat.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloader.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h"
#import "SDWebImageManager.h"
#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"
#import "SDWebImagePrefetcher.h"

    @interface mirsaProductTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mirsaProductTitle;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *mirsaProductDescription;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mirsaProductLogoImageView;    
    @end


**MyCustomCell.m**

#import "mirsaProductTableViewCell.h"

@implementation mirsaProductTableViewCell

@synthesize mirsaProductTitle = _mirsaProductTitle;
@synthesize mirsaProductDescription = _mirsaProductDescription;
@synthesize mirsaProductLogoImageView = _mirsaProductLogoImageView;
@synthesize mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView = _mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView;

-(void)prepareForReuse
{

}
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}





@end
```

**myTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mirsaCategories.h"
#import "sharedManagers.h"
#import "mirsaProductTableViewCell.h"
#import "constant.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIWebView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "SDWebImageCompat.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloader.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h"
#import "SDWebImageManager.h"
#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"
#import "SDWebImagePrefetcher.h"
#import "mirsaProduct.h"
#import "mirsaDetailedProductViewController.h"
#import "mirsaProductDetailsTableViewController.h"
@interface mirsaProductsTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) mirsaCategories *currentCategory;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *listOfProducts;
@property (nonatomic,strong) mirsaProduct *currentProduct;

@end
```

**myTableViewController.m**
due to not make the question too long i just import the cellOfRowAtIndexPath and the relevant method to it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mirsaProductCell";
    mirsaProductTableViewCell *cell = (mirsaProductTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[mirsaProductTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] ;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redRedColor green:redGreenColor blue:redBlueColor alpha:ALFA].CGColor;
        mirsaProduct *currentProduct = [self.listOfProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.mirsaProductTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product Code:%@",currentProduct.mirsaProductCode];
        cell.mirsaProductDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description: %@",currentProduct.mirsaProductDescription];
        [self downloadProductLogoImageView:cell :indexPath.row];
         for (int i = 0; i < currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage.count; i++) {
            [self downloadImageWithCached:currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage[i] :cell :indexPath.row :(NSInteger)i];
        }
    }


    else

    {
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redRedColor green:redGreenColor blue:redBlueColor alpha:ALFA].CGColor;
        mirsaProduct *currentProduct = [self.listOfProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.mirsaProductTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product Code:%@",currentProduct.mirsaProductCode];
        cell.mirsaProductDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description: %@",currentProduct.mirsaProductDescription];
        [self downloadProductLogoImageView:cell :indexPath.row];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage.count; i++) {
            [self downloadImageWithCached:currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage[i] :cell :indexPath.row :(NSInteger)i];
        }
    }


    return cell;
}






-(void)downloadProductLogoImageView:(mirsaProductTableViewCell *)cell :(NSInteger )index;
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [cell.mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
        mirsaProduct *currentProduct  = [self.listOfProducts objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *cachedKey  = currentProduct.mirsaProductImage;
        SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"productLogoImageView"];
        [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:cachedKey done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType)

         {
             if (image) {


                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [cell.mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
                     cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.image = image;

                 });
             }else{

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                     NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:currentProduct.mirsaProductImage];
                     [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader]downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageDownloaderLowPriority progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {




                         if (finished && image){
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                 [imageCache setMaxCacheAge:60*60*24];

                                 [imageCache storeImage:image
                                   recalculateFromImage:NO
                                              imageData:data
                                                 forKey:currentProduct.mirsaProductImage
                                                 toDisk:YES];
                             });



                             [cell.mirsaProductActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
                             cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.image = image;


                         }


                     }];









                 });
             }
         }];






    }


}
```

some links that i found on stack overflow [Tableview images chaging when scrolling using custom tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515183/tableview-images-chaging-when-scrolling-using-custom-tableview), [Incorrect cell data display when scrolling UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952171/incorrect-cell-data-display-when-scrolling-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

Hi as far i go through your code there two major changes that need to be done to solve your problem

1. if (cell == nil) {

   ```
   cell = [[mirsaProductTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] ;
   cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
   ```

**in this lines of code don't use nil instead of use cell Identifier**

2. to download image you don't need to write that much of code just write

   [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: yeah sure i am using SDWebImage for downloading and caching images

Comment: @danh can u give me a answer for the solution when i was testing my code on small data i didnt face this problem when data are go to be large this bug appear

Comment: As you scroll fast the images are downloading and they just messed around each other as images are currently downloading in async queue , either use sync queue or send me code will send you working copy
Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry @Satinder, I see the OP is using SDWebImage.

Comment: @ZakariaDarwish, ignoring the first point, this answer has the right idea.  SDWeb image does much of the work the OP code is attempting.  Give it the URL and let it do it's thing.

Comment: @satinder give me your mail address please

Comment: Its chaudhay044@gmail,com

Answer (score 0):

A third party library like SDWebImage is a reasonable idea, though a simple home-rolled version is not too tough to create.  Instead of a regular image view in the cell, use your own subclass, something like this:

```
// .h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AsynchImageView : UIImageView
- (void)setImageFromUrl:(NSString *)url placeholder:(UIImage *)placeholder;
@end

// .m
#import "AsynchImageView.h"

@implementation AsynchImageView

- (void)setImageFromUrl:(NSString *)url placeholder:(UIImage *)placeholder {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLCache *cache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [cache cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if (cachedResponse) {
        [self setImageFromData:cachedResponse.data];
    } else {
        self.image = placeholder;
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [cache storeCachedResponse:[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data] forRequest:request];
                [self setImageFromData:data];
            }
        }] resume];
    }
}

- (void)setImageFromData:(NSData *)data {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.image = image;
    });
}

@end
```

This checks to see if the image has been downloaded already, if it hasn't it sets a placeholder image and starts a download.  Upon completion, it sets the image to the downloaded one and caches it.

Remove all of the other image code when configuring the cell, and do this:

```
NSString *url  = currentProduct.mirsaProductImage;
[cell.mirsaProductLogoImageView setImageFromUrl: placeholder:];
```